# Relative Path not working RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, requirejs, relative-path

I am trying to use RequireJS to include `CCSEQ.WebAPI.js` in my `ExpenseUpload.js` file.  According to [RequireJS Documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) The base URL for RequireJS is the `data-main` folder specified in the html file (`WebResources/js/main` in my case).  However, I have been unable to include the `CCSEQ.WebAPI.js` file despite trying a variety of different relative path combinations.

I have tried starting my relative path with `/../`, specifying a `baseURL` in the config, and moving my `CCSEQ.WebAPI.js` file to different places in the folder structure without success.

Does anyone see a mistake I am making here?

### Error

[image: Error Message - Chrome Developer Tools]

### Project Structure

```
- WebResources
  - js
    - html
      - ExpenseUpload.html
    - lib
      - CCSEQ.WebAPI.js
    - main
      - ExpenseUpload.js
```

### ExpenseUpload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="expenseUploadApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Expense Upload</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />
    <link href="../css/ExpenseUpload.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body ng-controller="DisplayCtrl">
    <h1>Expense Upload</h1>

    <form>

        <label>Month:</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedMonth" ng-options="x for x in months">

        </select> 
        <label>Year:</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-options="y for y in years">
        </select><br/>
        <input type="file" id="csv-file" name="files" />
    </form>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/papaparse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/modules/ExpenseUploadModule.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/ExpenseUploadController.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/require.js" data-main="../js/main/ExpenseUpload.js"></script>
    <!--<img id="loading" src="../../Images/loading.gif" />-->
</body>
</html>
```

### ExpenseUpload.js

```
requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        '../lib/CCSEQ.WebAPI.js': ['Model/ExpenseTransaction', 'Model/ExpenseTransactionSet', 'API/ExpenseTransaction', 'API/ExpenseTransactionSet']
    }
});

require(["Model/ExpenseTransaction", "Model/ExpenseTransactionSet", "API/ExpenseTransaction", "API/ExpenseTransactionSet"], function (ExpenseTransactionModel, ExpenseTransactionSetModel, ExpenseTransactionAPI, ExpenseTransactionSetAPI) {
    // Code Here
});
```

Comment: I do not see `js` folder in your project structure. Is that an omission?

Comment: @SandeepNayak yes it is...I have updated the project structure

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles), it says

> The baseUrl is normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute ..

So your `baseUrl` is `main` folder and the `lib` is at the same level.

Hence use `lib/CCSEQ.WebAPI.js` in the bundle